# How long a process have been running (with Node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to get how long a process has been running using Node on Windows? I want to search for a specific process and get its running time.

Comment: Do you want to know the nodejs process uptime?Or some other system process?

Comment: Some other system process.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7):

> The `process.uptime()` method returns the number of seconds the current Node.js process has been running.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_uptime

&

> The `os.uptime()` method returns the system uptime in number of seconds.

https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_uptime

Comment: That is not related to my question at all.